# How to match exact string in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse all the files and verify if any of the file content has strings `TESTDIR or TEST_DIR`

Files contents might look something like:-

```
TESTDIR = foo 
include $(TESTDIR)/chop.mk
...
TEST_DIR := goldimage
MAKE_TESTDIR = var_make
NEW_TEST_DIR = tesing_var
```

Actually I am only interested in `TESTDIR ,$(TESTDIR),TEST_DIR` but in my case last two lines should be ignored. I am new to perl , Can anyone help me out with re-rex.

Comment: Please demonstrate your attempt to solve the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific about which things you are trying to match. For example, is it `TEST_DIR` only at the beginning of a line? Only when followed by `:=`?

Answer (score 1):

```
/\bTEST_?DIR\b/
```

- `\b` means a "word boundary", i.e. the place between a word character and a non-word character. "Word" here has the Perl meaning: it contains characters, numbers, and underscores.
- `_?` means "nothing or an underscore"

Comment: But if someone tries to add 'HELLO-TESTDIR-TEST' it should not work right.

Comment: You should be able to test it easily. If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: yes, i tested. It's not working when we add "-"

Comment: - is not a word character.

Answer (score 0):

Look at "characterset".

### Only   (space) surrounding allowed:

```txt
/^(.* )?TEST_?DIR /
```

- `^` beginning of the line
- `(.* )?` There may be some content `.*` but if, its must be followed by a space
- at the and says that a whitespace **must** be there. Otherwise use `( .*)?$` at the end.

### One of a given characterset is allowed:

Should the be other characters then a space be possible you can use a character class `[]`:

```txt
/^(.*[ \t(])?TEST_?DIR[) :=]/
```

- `(.*[ \t(])?` in front of `TEST_?DIR` may be a   (space) **or** a `\t` (tab) **or** `(` **or** nothing if the line starts with itself.
- afterwards there **must** be one of   (space) **or** `:` **or** `=` **or** `)`. Followd by anything (to "anything" belongs the "=" of ":=" ...).

### One of a given group is allowed:

So you need groups within `()` each possible group in there devided by a `|`:

```txt
/^(.*( |\t))?TEST_?DIR( | := | = )/
```

- In this case, at the beginning is no change to `[ \t]` because each group holds only one character   and `\t`.
- At the end, there must be   (single space) **or** `:=` (':=' surrounded by spaces) **or** `=` ('=' surrounded by spaces), following by anything...

You can use any combination...

```txt
/^(.*[ \t(])?TEST_?DIR([) =:]| :=| =|)/
```

Test it on [Debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/). (Use 'PCRE')